# Android Fragment Error: No View Found For ID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, shiva3d

The error in logcat: `E/FragmentManager(7158): No view found for id 0x7f05000d (com.mybiz.mygame:id/fragment_container) for fragment MainMenuFragment{4052d780 #0 id=0x7f05000d}`

Ok here is how the app is set up:

Two vars are created:

```
private static View oGoogleGamesView ;
private static RelativeLayout oViewGroup ;
```

Then in onCreate:

```
oViewGroup = new RelativeLayout ( this ) ;
setContentView ( oViewGroup ) ;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ) ;       
oGoogleGamesView        = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.ggmain, oViewGroup, false ) ;
```

And then I try to show the fragment:

```
// create fragments
mMainMenuFragment = new MainMenuFragment();

// listen to fragment events
mMainMenuFragment.setListener(this);

// add initial fragment (welcome fragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
        mMainMenuFragment).commit();
```

And here it crashes with the error at top. Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

**What can I do to show the fragment without crashing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your app view to oViewGroup:

```
setContentView ( oViewGroup ) ;
```

Then you inflate another view and leave it dangling:

```
oGoogleGamesView        = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.ggmain, oViewGroup, false ) ;
```

To actually have `oGoogleGamesView` as a layout in your app, you have to add it to the current view, only then can you reference the IDs contained in it:

```
oViewGroup.addView(oGoogleGamesView, LayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
in onCreate method
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
where yourLayout is xml file containing frameLayout that you have put in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however doing this will break my app, I need to keep my ContentView set to oViewGroup.